"machs" in "machs nicht so dramatisch"
I came cross this sentence in Collins

machs nicht so dramatisch!
don’t be so dramatic!

This seems to be an imperative sentence but machs is not among the imperative forms of "machen" that I am aware of. Neither can it be found in the conjugation table. What is this "machs" then?

It's a shortening.

Mach es nicht so dramatisch.

Those end-e are often dropped from imperatives, as the e of es is.

More precisely, it's a contraction.

IMHO it should be written as (mind the apostrophe): Mach's nicht so dramatisch

@planetmaker: Da die Auslassung aber nicht von "maches", sondern von "mach es" kommt, müsste die Apostrophierung so aussehen: "mach 's".

According to §  97 of the official orthography rules, the apostrophe is optional is such a case.
